# XPATH to select distinct first element if there are re occurring elements

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a reoccurring XML element

```
<comment>
    <cmnt_reas_typ>reason1</cmnt_reas_typ>
    <cmnt_txt>ABC</cmnt_txt>
</comment>
<comment>
    <cmnt_reas_typ>reason1</cmnt_reas_typ>
    <cmnt_txt>ABC</cmnt_txt>
</comment>
<comment>
    <cmnt_reas_typ>reason2</cmnt_reas_typ>
    <cmnt_txt>ABC</cmnt_txt>
</comment>
```

Basically, I want to display the `cmnt_txt` only once for a specific `cmnt_reas_typ`. So from example above I want to display `cmnt_txt` "ABC" only once for `cmnt_reas_typ` = "reason1". But the problem is `cmnt_reas_typ` is a dynamic value and I can not hardcode it in the XPath. Is there some way of saying that just return only one `cmnt_txt` for this `cmnt_reas_typ`? Or even if an XPath returns a boolean value `true` if it is the second occurrence for that `cmnt_reas_typ` that should be fine as well. It is for XPATH 1.0.

Comment: I do not understand the question, what does "check if the for that is already displayed on the screen" mean? Do you want to check for duplicates in `cmnt_reas_typ` or `cmnt_txt`? Which of those elements do you want to select? Or do you want an XPATH that will return a boolean for use in a test?

Comment: sorry I think some text got removed. Basically I want to display the cmnt_txt only once for a specific cmnt_reas_typ. So from example above I want to display cmnt_txt 'ABC' only once for cmnt_reas_typ = reason1. But the problem is cmnt_reas_typ is a dynamic value and I can not hardcode it in the xpath. Is there someway of saying that just return only one cmnt_txt for this  cmnt_reas_typ? It is XPATH 1.0

Comment: Please edit the post to add the missing text back.

Comment: Also please specify XPATH 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your need right, you want every comment type to produce one comment text (the first one), right? If that's the case, then I came up with this XPath:

```
//cmnt_txt[not(../cmnt_reas_typ/text() = ../preceding::cmnt_reas_typ/text())]
```

It takes all `cmnt_text` nodes whose `cmnt_reas_typ` is NOT equal to any preceding `cmnt_reas_typ`. Therefore, it should only take the first `cmnt_text` of every type, if there isn't anything I missed.

Comment: Presumably `cmnt_txt` could vary within a given 'cmnt_reas_typ` in which case some would be dropped by this method. OP did not specify this detail however.

Comment: @nine9ths Oh, right. My interpretation is that every comment type should print one (the first) comment text and that's it. But it is true that this is ambiguous from OP's description. I'll add this information to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On XPATH 2.0, you can use `distinct-values()`

Your expected XPATH should be something like

### Syntax:

```
distinct-values(//comment[cmnt_reas_typ='PASS-YOUR-DYNAMIC-VALUE']/cmnt_txt)
```

### Example:

```
distinct-values(//comment[cmnt_reas_typ='reason1']/cmnt_txt)
```

You will get list of unique results and show that one-by-one on the screen.

Comment: I think some of the text got removed! Anyway below is the the txt after the XML document 

I want to use an XPATH which will check if the cmnt_txt for that cmnt_reas_typ is already displayed on the screen. If yes then return false. I cannot hardcode the value for cmnt_reas_typ in the xpath as it can keep changing. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This xpath will return only `comment` elements which have unique `cmnt_txt` elements for each `cmnt_reas_type` in XPATH 1.0

```
comment[not(. = preceding::comment)]
```

Comment: `preceding::comment/concat(cmnt_reas_typ,cmnt_txt)` is strange in XPath 1.0. You can't call a function in a place for a location step. Is there a typo?